# Prove that the lim as $x$ approaches $a$ of $x^n$ equals $a^n$. (hint use induction)

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the lim as $x$ approaches $a$ of $x^n$ equals $a^n$. (hint use induction)

I'll be honest and say that I have no idea where to start with this problem. I am familiar with the epsilon delta definition but I am unclear as to how to involve induction and solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the base case $n=1$? That would be a good place to start. Then use properties about products and limits that you should know if you are being asked to solve this by induction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If we are going to use an induction argument, the following identity is useful:
$$x^{n+1}-a^{n+1}=x^{n+1}-xa^n+xa^n -a^{n+1}=x(x^n-a^n)+(x-a)a^n.$$

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the fact that the limit of a product is the product of the limits when both exist?

Comment: Easier, yes, but if we want to show more explicitly that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is $\dots$, then the above identity is handy.

Answer (score 1):

We will make use of the algebraic limit theorem, which says that if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)g(x))$ exists and is equal to $$(\lim_{x\to a} f(x))(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)).$$

Start with the case when $n=1$. I'll leave this to you, because it is an easy exercise in $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs. Let us assume this statement is true for $n=k$, that $\lim_{x\to a}x^k=a^k$. Then $$\lim_{x\to a}x^{k+1}=\lim_{x\to a}(x)(x^k).$$ Now we use the algebraic limit theorem:

$$\lim_{x\to a}x^{k+1}=(\lim_{x\to a}x)(\lim_{x\to a}x^k)=a(a^k)=a^{k+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

As the hint is induction, you should rely on $x^n=x^{n-1}x$, and establish that

$$\lim x^{n}=a^n\impliedby \lim (x^{n-1}x)=a^{n-1}a.$$

Then next step in the reasoning is that

$$a^{n-1}a=\lim x^{n-1}\cdot\lim x.$$

You should be able to fill the gap and handle the base case.